# angular 6 post request return correct object, but from service to component it gets undefined

Tags: typescript, post, angular6

I'm new in Angular, its architecture and typescript. I'm Struggling to achieve this simple thing and i didn't find any tutorial which i could follow. So i will really appreciate a little help with this.

I have a project or web app where I'm practicing a simple login process. In this case login component has a method to login where the app takes as arguments user and password from textfields and call a user service method which is in charge of doing a post request to a REST service. I've verified that Rest server send as body the answer I expect (in this case, the complete user in case of right user and password values). Login component subscribes to this call and I want it passing the value obtained as User in a property. BUT even when I get a JSON object as response, when service pass the value to login component it becomes undefined.

I know it seems simple but I think I'm misunderstanding the architecture of angular itself or maybe the observables... I don't know, I will appreciate any kind of advice in this.

Let me present you the code:

User class:

```
export class Usuario {
    // atributos
    nombreDeUsuario: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    fechaNacimiento: Date;
    karma: number; /*puntuación del usuario en la comunidad*/
    isAdmin: boolean; /*flag que establece si es administrador o no*/
    amigos: Usuario[]; /* lista de amigos del usuario */
    bloqueados: Usuario[]; /* lista de usuarios bloqueados */

    public constructor() { }

    public static conversor(convertible: any): Usuario {
        const usuario: Usuario = new Usuario();
        usuario.nombreDeUsuario = convertible.nombreDeUsuario;
        usuario.email = convertible.email;
        usuario.password = convertible.password;
        usuario.fechaNacimiento = convertible.password;
        usuario.karma = convertible.karma;
        usuario.amigos = convertible.amigos;
        usuario.bloqueados = convertible.bloqueados;
        console.log('convertido ' + usuario.toString());
        return usuario;
    }

    public toString(): String {
        return 'Usuario{' +
            'nombreDeUsuario=\'' + this.nombreDeUsuario + '\'' +
            ', email=\'' + this.email + '\'' +
            ', password=\'' + this.password + '\'' +
            ', fechaNacimiento=' + this.fechaNacimiento +
            ', karma=' + this.karma +
            ', isAdmin=' + this.isAdmin +
            ', amigos=' + this.amigos +
            ', bloqueados=' + this.bloqueados +
            '}';
    }
}
```

login component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsuariosService } from '../../servicios/usuarios.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Usuario } from '../../modelo/usuario';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  servicioUsuarios: UsuariosService;
  nombreDeUsuario: string;
  password: string;
  usuario: Usuario;

  constructor(servicioUsuarios: UsuariosService) {
    this.servicioUsuarios = servicioUsuarios;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  iniciarSesion() {
    console.log('se ejecuta');
    console.log(this.nombreDeUsuario);
    console.log(this.password);
    this.servicioUsuarios.inicioDeSesion(this.nombreDeUsuario, this.password)
      .subscribe((usuario) => { this.usuario = <Usuario>usuario; console.error(this.usuario);
      },
      (error) => { console.log(error); });
  }

}
```

and finally user service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Usuario } from '../modelo/usuario';

@Injectable()
export class UsuariosService {

  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  getUsuario(nombreDeUsuario: String) {
    let path: String = 'http://localhost:8080/usuarios/';
    path = path.concat(nombreDeUsuario.valueOf());
    return this.http.get(path.valueOf()).pipe(map(resultado => resultado.json() as Usuario));
  }

  inicioDeSesion(nombreDeUsuario: string, password: string) {
    const peticion: Login = {
      nombreDeUsuario: nombreDeUsuario,
      password: password
    };
    console.log(peticion);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', peticion)
      .pipe(map(resultado => {
        if (resultado == null) {
          throw new Error();
        } else {
          Usuario.conversor(resultado.json() as Usuario);
        }
      },
        error => console.log('Error capturado')
      ),
      catchError(err => err)
      );
  }

}

interface Login {
  nombreDeUsuario: string;
  password: string;
}
```

I've tried:

- Passing to login component directly response.json();
- Using a static method in User class to make a conversion of any to a User object.
- passing response without .json() directly and passing to the property the values directly from the response (but i got many error messages).

I know this code probably smells of bad design so I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Please, post a `console.log()` of the `resultado` you receive making this call:  `return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', peticion)
      .pipe(map(resultado => {...`.

Comment: sure:

_body: "{\"nombreDeUsuario\":\"paco\",\"email\":\"paco@paco.es\",\"password\":\"passwordpaco\",\"fechaNacimiento\":\"2018-07-19T21:01:03.000+0000\",\"karma\":2.5,\"amigos\":[],\"bloqueados\":[],\"admin\":false}"

headers: Object { _headers: Map(1), _normalizedNames: Map(1) }
​
ok: true
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
type: 2

Comment: What happens if you change this line of code `Usuario.conversor(resultado.json() as Usuario);` to this `Usuario.conversor(resultado.json());`?

Comment: It's pretty much the same, i only use "as" in an intend to force the type but without results

Comment: btw i forgot to add that in the console.error(this.usuario); line of login.component i get undefined

Comment: Sorry, I have no further idea.

Comment: @Lynx no problem, ty for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a little bit late but i've resolved this. My problem were two problems to be specific.

1 - I realized i didn't pass an object to the converter static function in the user class, in fact, REST server was sending the object i want to cast inside a "_body" field of the response. When i realized it, i changed it so i could retrieve the json object itself.

2 - Even with the object located. I wasn't really converting it to json and because of that i was getting undefined in all the fields. I was passing some object that was all strings, even in the name of the fields all the names had the same format "nameOfField":"valueOfField" instead of nameOfField:"valueOfField". I've resolved this with JSON.parse(response._body). Then, the converter method of the User class could retrieve all the fields without problem.

I hope this would be usefull to someone since i didn't get so much help here.